# find/use jquery array with help of a variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, slider

I'm quite at loss as to how to define my question properly.

I have a function for each .slider, and I also have a variable with "real values" for each slider. As the number of real values are different for the different sliders I thought I'd look up the number of alternatives with the help of counting values in the array and then setting max: *_* to that number.
Using [jQuery UI sliders](http://jqueryui.com/slider/).

My code:

```
   var costValues = [0, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 50000];
        var timeValues = ['Upp till 10 min', 'Upp till: 30 minuter', 'Upp till: 1h', 'Upp till tre timmar', 'Upp till en halvdag', 'Upp till en heldag', 'Upp till 2-3 dagar', 'Upp till en vecka', 'Upp till en månad', 'Upp till ett halvår', 'Upp till Ett år', 'Över ett år'];
        $( ".slider" ).each(function(i, e) {

..more Code
```

The content of "dennaArray" is the same as the name of the related Array, but I'm not able to look up .length for those arrays, as it interprets "dennaArray" as a variable itself with "char content".

Comment: All your variable names seem a bit confusing. `$` usually denotes a jQuery collection and `dennaArray` is not an array. Also, seems like you forgot some code at the end...

Comment: oops thought I'd removed the $. It was one of my trials to go with $

Comment: Perhaps I should remove all the code after the first few lines again? I don't really think they're relevant to the question, and might put ppl of (tldr?)

Comment: @Alisso: I think you have too little code right now. What's `dennaArray` for a start? Maybe you can set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a simple example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alisso,

From the first version of your question ....

First, make the arrays properties of a plain javascript object :

```
var lookupArrays = {
    'cost': [0, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 50000],
    'time': ['Upp till 10 min', 'Upp till: 30 minuter', 'Upp till: 1h', 'Upp till tre timmar', 'Upp till en halvdag', 'Upp till en heldag', 'Upp till 2-3 dagar', 'Upp till en vecka', 'Upp till en månad', 'Upp till ett halvår', 'Upp till Ett år', 'Över ett år']
};
```

Then inside the `.each()` function, you can select one of the two arrays from `lookupArrays` :

```
var dennaArray = lookupArrays[$(e).parent().attr('id')];
```

I'm not sure but the `slide:` function may then simplify to :

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $(e).parent().find('.slider-result').html( dennaArray[ui.value] );
},
```

Don't forget to localize variables with `var`. There are several in your code which should be localized but aren't.

### EDIT

Here's the code with some compaction and efficiency savings :

```
$(function() {
    var $$ = {//cache of static jquery objects
        content: $('#content').hide(),
        rightColumn: $('#rightColumn').hide(),
        aktiviter: $('div.aktivitet'),
        tagSwitches: $('li.tag'),
        skickaFeedback: $('#skickaFeedback'),
        sliders: $('.slider'),
        describers: $('.describers'),
        header: $('#header'),
        h3: $('h3')
    };
    var lookupArrays = {
        'cost': [0, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 50000],
        'time': ['Upp till 10 minuter', 'Upp till: 30 minuter', 'Upp till: 1h', 'Upp till tre timmar', 'Upp till en halvdag', 'Upp till en heldag', 'Upp till 2-3 dagar', 'Upp till en vecka', 'Upp till en månad', 'Upp till ett halvår', 'Upp till Ett år', 'Över ett år'],
        'timeSimplified': ['tid-1', 'tid-2', 'tid-3', 'tid-4', 'tid-5', 'tid-6', 'tid-7', 'tid-8', 'tid-9', 'tid-10', 'tid-11', 'tid-12']
    };
    var dolj, visaContent;
    $$.sliders.each(function(i, e) {
        var $e = $(e),
            $parent = $e.parent();
        var dennaArray = lookupArrays[$parent.attr('id')];
        $e.slider({
            animate: true,
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: dennaArray.length-1,
            step: 1,
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                clearTimeout(dolj);
                clearTimeout(visaContent);
            },
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                clearTimeout(dolj);
                clearTimeout(visaContent);
                switch($parent.attr('id')) {
                    case 'cost':
                        var txt = (ui.value == 0) ? 'Det måste vara gratis.' : 'Upp till: ' + dennaArray[ui.value] + ':-';
                    break;
                    case 'time':
                    default:
                        var txt = dennaArray[ui.value];
                }
                $parent.find('.slider-result').html( txt );
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                dolj = setTimeout(function () {
                    $$.sliders.add($$.describers).add($$.header.find('h2')).slideUp();
                    $$.h3.css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    $parent.next().children().andSelf().slideDown();
                    $$.header.find('h1').animate({
                        'font-size': '1.4em',
                    }, 1000, function() {
                    });
                }, 3500);
                visaContent = setTimeout(function() {
                    $$.content.add($$.rightColumn).slideDown();
                }, 400);
            }
        });
    });
    //Om du klickar på ngn av frågorna så visas slidern igen så att du kan ändra dina parametrar :D
    $('.question').click(function(){
        $(this).show().parent().children().toggle();
    });
    $$.rightColumn.on('click', 'li.tag', function(){
        $$.aktiviter.hide();
        $tagSwitch = $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $$.tagSwitches.each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                var filterID = $(this).attr('id').replace("filterid-",'');
                $$.aktiviter.filter("." + filterID).show();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#skickaFeedback').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveFeedback.php",
            data: "someFeedback=" + $(this).prev().val(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                alert('Tack för din feedback!');
                $('#skickaFeedback').prev().val('');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: "var lookupArrays = {
    'cost': [0, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 50000];
    'time': ['Upp till 10 min', 'Upp till: 30 minuter', 'Upp till: 1h', 'Upp till tre timmar', 'Upp till en halvdag', 'Upp till en heldag', 'Upp till 2-3 dagar', 'Upp till en vecka', 'Upp till en månad', 'Upp till ett halvår', 'Upp till Ett år', 'Över ett år'];
};" gives me error?

Comment: I think that perhaps there should be a "," instead of ; after 50000] (I'm still trying out this awesomeness. :D

Comment: Alisso, you think correctly, I have edited above (one `;` changed to `,` and one `;` deleted).

Comment: If you should like to see the result, here's my working demo: http://victoriawagman.se/projekt/aktivitetshanteraren/   :)

Comment: Hey, that's coming on nicely :) With a little thought, certain parts of the code will simplify. I can get the whole script down to about 76 lines (untested), which is just over half its current size.

Comment: wow, cool. Where should I start digging? I mean, what can I do?

Comment: Alisso, you can do all sorts but I'm afraid my edits already hit the cutting room floor. I'm about to drive home from my parents' place - will see if I can re-create the compact code later this afternoon/evening.

Comment: OK, take a look at my edit above. I didn't quite get the code down to 76 lines this time but still managed to compact it quite a tot. The compaction comes from a variety of techniques including jQuery method chaining and removing and blank lines and `console.log` statements. I also spotted a much better way to handle `li.tag` button clicks - this code is more compact and will be less memory hungry. The sliders' `slide` handler also reduced by several lines.

Comment: I have a packed day at Uni/Formula tomorrow, I'll look into it tomorrow evening or on wednesday if I get back to late tomorrow. I'm reading it through now though.